# c++: std::in, _getch() работают некорректно

Tags: c++, отладка, cin

Для отладки программы необходимо приостанавливать работу программы, порционно выводить некоторую информацию на экран и затем по команде заново продолжать работу (это для отладки, выводится визуализация некоторых данных, поэтому брейтпоинты и т.д. не помогут).

Сначала для остановки и запуска использовал `_getch()`, но после первой остановки и запуска программа второй раз `_getch()` игнорировала и останавливалась только на третьем, четвертый игнорировала, останавливалась на пятом и т.д.

Тогда заменил  `_getch()` на `std::in >> value`, но там ситуация еще более странная - первый `std::in` срабатывает, следующие игнорируются напрочь (тоже самое и для связки `std::in` и `_getch()` - после первого `std::in` все остальное игрорируется).

**Подскажите в чём может быть дело?**

У меня скорее всего происходила запись за пределы выделенной памяти (ее и ищу) - может ли это приводить к таким результатам? Или я что-то не так вызываю?

P.S.

Код слишком большой, чтобы из него выделить некоторый самодостаточный воспроизводимый кусок, но вызов выглядит так:

```
void myfunc()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    show_debug(true, position);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    _getch();

    myfunc(); // у меня вложенные вызовы, но не глубокие (глубина до 4)
}
```

даже, если сделать так:

```
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << '*' << std::endl;
_getch();
```

будет воспроизводиться по 2 `*`

**P.P.S.**

Заметил, что в DEBUG такая проблема исчезает (точно куда-то течет!)

Comment: Вы для `_getch()` что нажимаете? Не какую-нибудь из расширенных клавиш (ну, там, стрелку, F-какую-то и т.д.)? Уж очень на это похоже... `std::in` - вы имеете в виду `std::cin`? В каком режиме работаете? Вобщем, показали бы вы [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: Harry, нажимаю исключительно пробел, а когда использовал `std::cin`, то `y`
В основной пост добавил кусок кода, но вряд ли он что покажет

Comment: можете попробовать перед вызовом `_getch` чистить буфер ввода с клавиатуры, например так: `while(_kbhit()) _getch();`

Comment: ascade, никакого эффекта - то же самое все, я грешу на то, что в память пишу некорректно (скорее всего так), поэтому программа ведет себя так странно